# How to set environment specific properties in c#?

Tags: c#, configuration, configuration-files

I have a project where I want to store my data in different tables based on different environments, which can be set using 
    'npm config set  true'

For example, I want to write my data to Table1_Dev in Dev environment and to Table1_Prod in prod environment.

I want to define my configuration properties per environment in a configuration file and then read it as per the environment in my c# code.

I can do it easily in Typescript, but I can't find a good way to do it in C#. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Are using the same database for all the environments? For configuration files per environment you need to learn about configuration transformation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's a broad question.  There are several ways to do it.  Google configuration transforms.  I've done it with YAML in Java.  I imagine the same tech can work in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

> Table1_Dev in Dev environment and to Table1_Prod in prod environment.

That's wrong, rather you should have separate DB instance for different environment and target them.

You can define separate XML or JSON configuration file like `Configuration_DEV.json`. Have you environment specific properties there. In your code read the json file and deserialize to a setting class accordingly.

Example `Configuration_DEV.json`

```
{
  "DevSettings": {
    "DBConnectionString": "some value",
    "DatabaseName": "DevDB"
  }
}
```

You can define a class like

```
public class DevSettings
{
  public string DBConnectionString { get; set; }
  public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hm.  I assumed the table names were the same, but if he actually wants to target different tables then yes I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the web.config file like so

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

Then you can reference it is your code.

What you can do next is setup publishing profiles to overwrite the key for each environnement.

Then you have to add a .config overwrite for the profile you've just created.

In the overwrite .config you can do this

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="" value="" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" /> 
</appSettings>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx